# Ubuntu 19.04 fails to USB boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb

I've built a new PC and installed Windows 10 without any problems, but I am having trouble installing / booting any Linux distribution. I made bootable USB via Rufus and also tried to dd from another computer, but I get same issue.

Whenever I boot from the grub menu I get bunch of errors from systemd, which say `failed to start GRUB failed boot detection`, `failed to start login prompts`, `failed to start emergency shell` and so on.

[image: boot failed]

Specs:

- Motherboard - ASRock b450 Steel Legend
- CPU - Ryzen 5 3600
- GPU - NVIDIA 1660

This problem is not limited to Ubuntu. I've tried Fedora and Solus, but can't get them to boot either.

Comment: Do you get a command prompt after the error stream stops? If so try typing into it `systemctl status sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount` ( and a few other of the suggestions in that output). See what you get.

Comment: @StephenBoston no

Comment: could it be this issue ? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1835809

Comment: if so then how do I get latest iso? from where I downloaded last modified version is from april

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1835809 ,  solution is to boot from older distro and then upgrade to 19.04

Comment: Hope you added yourself to "this bug affects me"?